# Installing epel-release on Centos7 causes "yum update" and "yum repolist" to throw 404's

Tags: centos, yum

I am new to using Centos and installing packages. I am currently trying to add epel-release to a Centos7 server. I am doing the following:

1. `sudo yum repolist` - This works as expected
2. `sudo yum install epel-release` - This works as expected
3. `sudo yum repolist` - This returns many 404's for epel repositories (i.e: `https://pubmirror1.math.uh.edu/fedora-buffet/epel/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml.asc: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 404 - Not Found`)

I am trying to pass a DISASTIG compliance scan, so I cannot simply disable the repo's GPG check. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Does the first item under "Known Issues" here help: https://wiki.centos.org/Manuals/ReleaseNotes/CentOS7.1908 Note there is a difference between "gpgcheck" in your /etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo file and "repo_gpgcheck" in /etc/yum.conf

Answer (score 1):

I found that curl was out of date and was causing GPG checking to fail. I did the following to fix the issue.

1. `sudo yum install epel-release -y`
2. `sudo yum update -y`
3. `sudo yum update curl --nogpg -y`
4. `sudo yum repolist`

The last repolist check will now not throw 404 errors.